Finding partial derivative of given MMSE .

Given in the image, how did we find equation 25 from equation 24? Even if we take the partial derivative of E with respect to A, how will we treat A hermitian, and what will be its derivative with respect to A? Apart from this for the first term, it should be zero, and the second and third term derivative is there which is equal to  Rh*P- P(hermitian) Rh. HOW can we combine these two terms and get one term in end in equation 25. Does the trace affect the derivative with hermitian.

Please define these matrices and their dimensions.

$\def\tr{\operatorname{tr}}$
$\def\qty#1{\left( #1 \right)}$
As @Digitallis mentioned a lot of your terms are undefined so I must guess that
$R_H$ is a Hermitian matrix with the property $(R_H)^H=R_H$ where $(-)^H$ denotes the conjugate transpose of a complex matrix. If this is the case then,
$$
G = P^H R_H P + \sigma^2_n r I
\implies
G^H = G
$$
so lets denote $P^H R_H P + \sigma^2_n r I$ as $G_H$.
$\def\re{\operatorname{Re}}$
$\def\im{\operatorname{Im}}$
Another question is what is the meaning of $\def\pdv#1#2{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}$ $\def\cE{\mathcal{E}}$ $\pdv{\cE}{A}$ where $\cE$ is  a real number and $A$ is a complex matrix?  $A=\re(A)+i\im(A)$ so we have to derive the derivative of $\cE$ w.r.t. $\re(A)$ and $\im(A)$. Note that,
$$
\tr\qty{R_HPA} + \tr\qty{A^HP^HR_H} =
\tr\qty{R_HPA+A^HP^HR_H}=
\tr\qty{R_HPA+\qty{R_HPA}^H}
$$
and for any complex matrix $M$,
$$
M+M^H = \re(M) + i \im(M) + \re(M)^T - i \im(M)^T
=\qty{\re(M)+\re(M)^T}+ i \qty{\im(M)-\im(M)^T}
$$
Since $\tr(M+M^T)=2 \tr(M)$ and $\tr(M-M^T)=0$,
$$
\tr\qty{R_HPA+\qty{R_HPA}^H}=
2\tr\qty{\re\qty{R_HPA}}=2\tr\qty{R_H\re\qty{PA}}
$$
where,
$$
\re\qty{PA} =
\re(P)\re(A)-\im(P)\im(A)
$$
We also have,
$$
\eqalign{
A^H G_H A & = \qty{\re(A)^T-i\im(A)^T}G_H\qty{\re(A)+i\im(A)} \\
& =
\re(A)^TG_H \re(A) + \im(A)^T G_H \im(A)
-i \qty{\im(A)^T G_H \re(A) - \re(A)^T G_H \im(A)}
}
$$
Since $\re(A)^T G_H \im(A)=\qty{\im(A)^T G_H \re(A)}^T$,
$$
\tr\qty{\im(A)^T G_H \re(A) - \re(A)^T G_H \im(A)}=0
$$
and,
$$
\tr\qty{A^H G_H A } =
\tr\qty{\re(A)^TG_H \re(A)} + \tr\qty{\im(A)^T G_H \im(A)}
$$
Lets use these results to rewrite $\cE$ as the sum of,
$$
\eqalign{
  \def\cE{\mathcal{E}}
  \def\tsr#1#2#3{{{#1}^{#2}}_{#3}}
  \def\tsar#1#2#3{{{#1}_{#2}}^{#3}}
  \def\tr{\operatorname{tr}}
  \def\qty#1{\left( #1 \right)}
  \cE_R & = \frac{1}{2}\tr\qty{R_H} - 2\tr\qty{R_H \re(P)\re(A)} + \tr\qty{\re(A)^TG_H \re(A)}  \\
  \cE_I & =  \frac{1}{2}\tr\qty{R_H} + 2\tr\qty{R_H \im(P)\im(A)} + \tr\qty{\im(A)^TG_H \im(A)}
}
$$
For both $\cE_R$ and $\cE_I$ we have an expression of the form,
$$
\cE = \frac{1}{2}\tr\qty{R_H} \mp 2 \tr\qty{R_H P A} + \tr\qty{A^T G_H A}
= \frac{1}{2}\tr\qty{R_H} \mp 2  \sum_{i,j,k}\qty{R_H}_{ij}P_{jk}A_{ki}
+ \sum_{i,j,k} \qty{A^T}_{ij}\qty{G_H}_{jk} A_{ki}
$$
where we must calculate the derivative of $\cE$ w.r.t. $A$:
$\def\pdv#1#2{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}$
$$
\eqalign{
\def\df{\mathsf{d}}
\pdv{\cE}{A_{qr}} & = \mp 2  \sum_{i,j,k}\qty{R_H}_{ij}P_{jk}\pdv{A_{ki}}{A_{qr}}
+ \sum_{i,j,k} \qty{\pdv{\qty{A^T}_{ij}}{A_{qr}}\qty{G_H}_{jk} A_{ki}
+\qty{A^T}_{ij}\qty{G_H}_{jk} \pdv{A_{ki}}{A_{qr}}} \\
& = \mp 2  \sum_{i,j,k}\qty{R_H}_{ij}P_{jk}\delta_{kq}\delta_{ir}
+ \sum_{i,j,k} \qty{\pdv{A_{ji}}{A_{qr}}\qty{G_H}_{jk} A_{ki}
+\qty{A^T}_{ij}\qty{G_H}_{jk} \pdv{A_{ki}}{A_{qr}}} \\
& = \mp 2  \sum_{j}\qty{R_H}_{rj}P_{jq}
+ \sum_{i,j,k} \qty{\delta_{jq}\delta_{ir}\qty{G_H}_{jk} A_{ki}
+\qty{A^T}_{ij}\qty{G_H}_{jk} \delta_{kq}\delta_{ir}} \\
& = \mp 2  \sum_{j}\qty{R_H}_{rj}P_{jq}
+ \sum_{k} \qty{G_H}_{qk} A_{kr}
+ \sum_j \qty{A^T}_{rj}\qty{G_H}_{jq} \\
& = \mp 2  \sum_{j}\qty{R_H}_{rj}P_{jq}
+ \sum_{k} \qty{A^T}_{rk}\qty{G_H}_{kq} 
+ \sum_j \qty{A^T}_{rj}\qty{G_H}_{jq} & \text{$G_H^T=G_H$}\\
& = \mp 2  \sum_{j}\qty{R_H}_{rj}P_{jq}
+ 2\sum_{k} \qty{A^T}_{rk}\qty{G_H}_{kq} \\
& = \mp 2 \qty{R_H P}_{rq} +2 \qty{A^TG_H}_{rq}
}
$$
The optimal value for $A$ is obtained by solving $\pdv{\cE}{A_{qr}}=0$:
$$
\mp 2R_H P + 2 A^TG_H = 0 \Rightarrow G_H A = \pm P^T R_H 
 \Rightarrow A = \pm {G_H}^{-1} P^T R_H 
$$
We have,
$$
\eqalign{
  \re(A_o) & = {G_H}^{-1} \re(P)^T R_H \\
  \im(A_o) & = -{G_H}^{-1} \im(P)^T R_H
}
$$
and so,
$$
A_o=\re(A_o) + i \im(A_o)=
{G_H}^{-1} \qty{\re(P)^T-i\im(P)^T}R_H 
= {G_H}^{-1} P^H R_H
$$

Rh here is basically the correlation matrix of Channel Matrix H, where Rh=Expectation[HH(hermitian)] . Apart from this talking about ε it is basically the Mean square error. to optimize it we have find partial derivative of equation with respect to A for optimal A

OK then my guess was correct. Try to use the math editor.
